# angular change input type from directive

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I am making a currency directive.  What i want to achieve is this.

1. when i click the input, change the input type to "number" (so i can take advantage of the type="number") 
   when i click out of the input, change the input type text (so i can format the number to currency, because type=number only accepts numeric values).

It works IF, i put the input changing function in the controller, BUT it works only it i have ONE input. (see commented code in .html and script.js

The solution is to put the function inside the directive.

I've tried with no success.

here is a plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/4l6CwIvZqCdIem5VXvtk?p=preview

link code from the directive

```
link: function(scope, el, attrs) {

    el.val($filter('currency')(scope.amount));

    el.bind('focus', function() {
      scope.typeNumber();
      el.val(scope.amount);
    });

    el.bind('input', function() {
      scope.amount = parseFloat(el.val());
      scope.$apply();
    });

    el.bind('blur', function() {
      scope.typeText()
      el.val($filter('currency')(scope.amount));
    });

    scope.typeNumber = function() {
      scope.t = 'number';
      console.log(scope.t);
    }
       scope.typeText = function() {
      scope.t = 'text';
      console.log(scope.t);
    }

  }
```

for some reason the functions do not run on 'blur' and 'focus'. I tried scope.$apply() with no success either.

any idea ow it can be done?

I don't know if watchers should be used, (i'd rather not)

thank you

Comment: use @HotListener to listen user events https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#respond-to-user-initiated-events

Comment: @Eliseo your comment is about angular 2+ while the question is about AngularJs

Comment: :glups: :glups:, sorry